# Defining constants in python class, is self really needed?

Tags: python, constants, visibility

I want to define a set of constants in a class like:

```
class Foo(object):
   (NONEXISTING,VAGUE,CONFIRMED) = (0,1,2)
   def __init__(self):
       self.status = VAGUE
```

However, I get

```
NameError: global name 'VAGUE' is not defined
```

Is there a way of defining these constants to be visiable inside the class without resorting to `global` or `self.NONEXISTING = 0` etc.?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

When you assign to names in the class body, you're creating attributes of the class. You can't refer to them without referring to the class either directly or indirectly. You can use `Foo.VAGUE` as the other answers say, or you can use `self.VAGUE`. You do not have to *assign* to attributes of `self`.

Usually, using `self.VAGUE` is what you want because it allows subclasses to redefine the attribute without having to reimplement all the methods that use them -- not that that seems like a sensible thing to do in this particular example, but who knows.

Answer (score 11):

try instead of:

```
self.status = VAGUE
```

this one:

```
self.status = Foo.VAGUE
```

you MUST specify the class

Answer (score 4):

This one is NOT RECOMMENDED FOR ANY CODE by any means, but an ugly hack like below can be done.
I did this just to have better understanding of Python AST API, so anyone who uses this in real-world code should be shot before it does any harm :-)

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8-unix -*-
#
# AST hack to replace symbol reference in instance methods,
# so it will be resolved as a reference to class variables.
#

import inspect, types, ast

def trim(src):
    lines = src.split("\n")
    start = lines[0].lstrip()
    n = lines[0].index(start)
    src = "\n".join([line[n:] for line in lines])
    return src

#
# Method decorator that replaces symbol reference in a method
# so it will use symbols in belonging class instead of the one
# in global namespace.
#
def nsinclude(*args):
    # usecase: @nsinclude()
    # use classname in calling frame as a fallback
    stack = inspect.stack()
    opts  = [stack[1][3]]

    def wrap(func):
        if func.func_name == "tempfunc":
            return func

        def invoke(*args, **kw):
            base = eval(opts[0])

            src = trim(inspect.getsource(func))
            basenode = ast.parse(src)

            class hackfunc(ast.NodeTransformer):
                def visit_Name(self, node):
                    try:
                        # if base class (set in @nsinclude) can resolve
                        # given name, modify AST node to use that instead
                        val = getattr(base, node.id)

                        newnode = ast.parse("%s.%s" % (opts[0], node.id))
                        newnode = next(ast.iter_child_nodes(newnode))
                        newnode = next(ast.iter_child_nodes(newnode))
                        ast.copy_location(newnode, node)
                        return ast.fix_missing_locations(newnode)
                    except:
                        return node

            class hackcode(ast.NodeVisitor):
                def visit_FunctionDef(self, node):
                    if func.func_name != "tempfunc":
                        node.name = "tempfunc"
                        hackfunc().visit(node)

            hackcode().visit(basenode)

            newmod = compile(basenode, '<ast>', 'exec')
            eval(newmod)
            newfunc = eval("tempfunc")
            newfunc(*args, **kw)
        return invoke


    # usecase: @nsinclude
    if args and isinstance(args[0], types.FunctionType):
        return wrap(args[0])

    # usecase: @nsinclude("someclass")
    if args and args[0]:
        opts[0] = args[0]
    return wrap

class Bar:
    FOO = 987
    BAR = 876

class Foo:
    FOO = 123
    BAR = 234

    # import from belonging class
    @nsinclude
    def dump1(self, *args):
        print("dump1: FOO = " + str(FOO))


    # import from specified class (Bar)
    @nsinclude("Bar")
    def dump2(self, *args):
        print("dump2: BAR = " + str(BAR))

Foo().dump1()
Foo().dump2()
```

Comment: +1 for the effort and the reflection hacking. Not too useful in this scenario, but reflection hacking is always fun!

Answer (score 3):

The only way is to access it through the class name such as

```
Foo.VAGUE
```

If accessing just VAGUE inside the `__init__` function, or a function, it must be declared inside that to access it the way you want.

Using self is for the instance of the class also.

Comment: ok, thats too bad. I recall that you could do something like what I was trying to do in java? I'm not sure.

Comment: I am pretty sure you can do just what you asked in Java!

Comment: And I'm pretty sure that you cant do 90% of the other stuff you want to do in java.

Answer (score 3):

In Python3, you can also reference `VAGUE` as:

```
type(self).VAGUE
```

This way, you are clearly referencing it as a class attribute and not an object attribute, yet this way is robust against a name change of the class. Also if you override `VAGUE` in a subclass, the value from the subclass will be used, just like if you were to use `self.VAGUE`.

Note that this method does not appear to work in Python2, at least not in my tests, where `type(self)` returned `instance` instead of the class I instantiated. Therefore Thomas Wouters's answer is probably preferable, considering how widespread Python2 still is.